# How to fix maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project BlackSheepApplication: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.blacksheep.BlackSheepApplication, com.blacksheep.MoveCodeTest, com.blacksheep.NameChangePlagiarismDemo] -> [Help 1
```

This was working completely fine in my local machine, 
when I am trying to package using maven it giving the above error

Comment: Step 1: read the error message. Step 2. Understand that it complains about multiple possible main classes. Step 3. If there should be only one main class, remove or fix the other ones, otherwise, try to discover how to explicitly specify the main class instead of letting the maven plugin find it. Step 4. Google for the Spring boot documentation. Step 5. Use Ctrl-F to find the chapter about the Spring-Boot Maven plugin. Step 6. Click on the link to the plugin documentation. Step 7. Read the documentation and find out how to specify the main class. All this took me 30 seconds.

Comment: @JB Nizet  It could almost make it an answer as a general guideline for beginners  that don't have the reflexes :)